# Unity Building Library\Bee\artifacts\Android\d8kzr\ntlq_main.o failed

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

i tried to build my unity project for android platform. Then, i got an issue when i built the project

Building Library\Bee\artifacts\Android\d8kzr\ntlq_main.o failed with output:
*project folder*\Library\Bee\artifacts\Android\il2cppOutput\cpp\main.c(2,10): fatal error: 'gtk/gtk.h' file not found
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
UnityEditor.GenericMenu:CatchMenu (object,string[],int)

Please, help me!

To solve this problem, i tried to manually install gtk with MSYS2. I tried to re-import all externall package too. Can someone please help me and describe was wrong with my project or build setting?

Comment: This problem has solved itself. I realized that  i tried to build in windows, meanwhile gtk is a library from linux. That library used in some package that has plugin for linux. So, i just tried to deleted that plugin, and solved